# Getting inner div element in <li> tags with simple dom html library

Tags: simple-html-dom

```
<li class="textes even">
                    <div class="author"> <strong>Misawa <span class="familyName">Mamie</span></strong></div>
                    <div class="title"><a href="1640" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr" hreflang="fr"><span xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">Aliénation ou acculturation coloniale&nbsp;?</span></a> <span class="fullText">[Texte intégral]</span></div>
                    <div class="subtitle">Taiwan et l’«&nbsp;énigme&nbsp;» d’un succès&nbsp;: le Festival du film japonais de Taipei (1960)</div>
                    <div class="altertitle" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><span xml:lang="en" lang="en">Estrangement or Colonial Acculturation? Taiwan and the Riddle of Japanese Movies Popularity: the Japenese Film Festival of Taipei, 1960</span></div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="textes odd">
                    <div class="author"> <strong>Nanta <span class="familyName">Arnaud</span></strong></div>
                    <div class="title"><a href="1676" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr" hreflang="fr"><span xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">Les débats au <span style="font-variant:small-caps;">xx</span><sup>e</sup>&nbsp;siècle sur la légalité de l’annexion de la Corée&nbsp;: histoire et légitimité</span></a> <span class="fullText">[Texte intégral]</span></div>
                    <div
```

I would like to retrieve the divs where `class=author` in each `<li>` element with simple html dom ( http://agichevski.com/2013/11/23/php-simple-html-dom-parser/ ).

I got the `<li>` element by doing this :

```
 foreach($html_obj->find('li.textes') as $bt) {
}
```

How do I manipulate the $bt object to get the nested divs ?

thank you

Comment: $bt->find('span.familyName')->innertext;

Answer (score 0):

To get the author from `$bt`:

```
$bt->find("div[class=author]")
```

or you can do it directly from `$html_obj`:

```
foreach ($html_obj->find("li div[class=author]") as $auth)
{   echo $auth . "\n";
}
```

returns

```
<div class="author"><strong>Misawa <span class="familyName">Mamie</span></strong></div>
<div class="author"><strong>Nanta <span class="familyName">Arnaud</span></strong></div>
```